# psm: match is better but eQQ plot is worse

Tags: r, matching

I'm trying out a PSM match, and I'm not sure what to do with this result. After the match, the standard mean diff drops for the overall distance and for the tsale varible. But looking at it graphically, the tsale seems to do a lot worse:

Love plot:

[image]

Plot for individual covariates:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standardized mean differences only describe balance on the covariate means, but that doesn't mean the entire covariate distributions are at all similar. That's why it's so important to use balance measures other than mean differences, such as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic (called ECDF Max in `MatchIt`), variance ratio, or overlapping statistic. `MatchIt` and `cobalt` offer many options to assess balance beyond the means numerically and graphically.

In your example, although the difference in means for `tsale` is smaller after matching, the other features of the distributions in the treatment groups may be quite different. Using `plot(., type = "density")` can more intuitively display what features of the distributions differ, and you can target these differences by adding additional terms to the propensity score model or attempting other forms of matching, like by adding a caliper or exact matching constraint or by using genetic matching.

Comment: Thanks! Also, all your guides online are extremely helpful.